# listFiles() but ignore a subdirectory in Android

Tags: android, file

I need to get a list of files but ignore a particular subdirectory. For example here is a sample structure.

```
Content
->1
-->file_a.mp4
-->file_b.mp4
->2
-->file_c.mp4
-->file_d.mp4
->Bonus
-->1
--->file_e.mp4
--->file_f.mp4
```

I need to be able to get a list of files/directories that excludes the bonus directory.

I also need to separate list the files for the bonus directory, but I think that can be easily solved by using the normal method.

How do I perform a list files, but ignore a directory?

Here is my sample code that is going to return everything

```
final List<Boxset> boxsets = getCloudBoxsetsWithTrackData(context);
        final File[] boxsetFiles = dir.listFiles();
        if (boxsetFiles != null)
        {
            for (File subDir : boxsetFiles)
            {
                if (subDir.isDirectory())
                {
                    for (Boxset boxset : boxsets)
                    {
                        if (subDir.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(boxset.persistentId)))
                        {
                            DBHandler.getInstance(context).moveBoxsetToDeviceList(boxset);
                            DownloadLibrarian.getInstance(context).stopDownload(boxset);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `FileFilter` to obtain a list of sub-directories that doesn't include `Bonus`

```
File[] nonBonusDirs = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
  @Override public boolean accept(File file) {
    return file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("bonus");
  }
});
```

You can then obtain a list of all files not in the `Bonus` directory

```
List<File> filesNotInBonusDir = new ArrayList<>();

for (File directory : nonBonusDirs) {
  filesNotInBonusDir.addAll(Arrays.asList(directory.listFiles()));
}
```

Though of course these shenanigans are much nicer in Kotlin thanks to `flatMap` ;)

```
val filesNotInBonusDir: List<File> = dir.listFiles()
    .filter { it.isDirectory && !it.name.equals("bonus", ignoreCase = true) }
    .flatMap { it.listFiles().toList() }
```

Comment: Been slowly converting to Kotlin but this class isn't quite ready. Could you also provide a Java solution?

Comment: Woops! For some reason I completely failed to notice this was a Java question, not a Kotlin question. Updated.